# How to align Button in a JPanel this way

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to create a graphic interface using `JPanel` and `JButton`.  So far it's good except when I'm creating the `JButton` instances, they seem to align within the same line.  I want every button to be in one line, not all in the same line.

How do I achieve the desired effect?

```
public class Interface  extends JFrame{

    public  Interface ()
    {
    //frame 
        super("Panel");
        pack();
        setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);

    //declaration container
    Container c;
    c=getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //declaration des panel avec leurs caracteristiques

    JPanel menu =new JPanel();
    JPanel MessageList =new JPanel();
    JPanel about=new JPanel();

    menu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    MessageList.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    about.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    menu.setBackground(Color.blue);
    MessageList.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    about.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    c.add(menu,BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.add(MessageList,BorderLayout.EAST);
    c.add(about,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //--------Button---------------------
    JButton button1=new JButton("button1");
    JButton button2=new JButton("Button2");

    menu.add(button1);
    menu.add(button2);
    //-----------------------------
        }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Interface Message=new Interface();
        Message.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to use a layout other than `FlowLayout()`. Check out this tutorial on effectively using layouts http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/GUI/AWTLayoutMgr/shortcourse.html

Comment: Or the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Also you should invoke pack() and setVisible(true) AFTER you have added all the components to the frame.

Comment: Ok , your comment were a big help thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stack components, use [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html). Also, make sure to follow the suggestions made by [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr).

See also:

- [How to Use BoxLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested layout.  The yellow and blue panels each have their own layout, and are then placed in constraints of the larger layout.

[image: Message GUI]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface  extends JFrame{

    public  Interface ()
    {
        //frame
        super("Panel");

        //declaration container
        Container c;
        c=getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.setBackground(Color.white);
        //declaration des panel avec leurs caracteristiques

        JPanel menu =new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,3,3));
        JPanel messageList =new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel about=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        menu.setBackground(Color.blue);
        messageList.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        messageList.add(new JLabel("'messageList' padder"));
        about.setBackground(Color.green);
        about.add(new JLabel("'about' padder"));

        JPanel menuConstrain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        menuConstrain.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        menuConstrain.add(menu,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(menuConstrain,BorderLayout.WEST);
        c.add(messageList,BorderLayout.EAST);
        c.add(about,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //--------Button---------------------
        JButton button1=new JButton("button1");
        JButton button2=new JButton("Button2");

        menu.add(button1);
        menu.add(button2);
        //-----------------------------

        pack();
        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Interface Message=new Interface();
        Message.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

For a more comprehensive example of using nested layouts, see [`NestedLayoutExample.java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271).

---

BTW - That is some confusingly written code!

1. It uses the common 'camel case' nomenclature sometimes, but not others.
2. There is a concrete class with name `Interface`.
3. There is a panel named `menu`.
4. The frame appears on-screen titled `Panel`.
5. Try putting comments in Ethiopian next time.  I read that about as well as I read French.
6. That all combined with the inconsistent indentation, results in code that is hard to read & understand.

Is this a poor man's form of obfuscation?

---

Note that Swing GUIs should be created on the EDT.